# Handling multiple StoredProcedureItemReader calls

Tags: java, spring-batch

I have to implement below use case in a Spring Batch job:

1. Read a list of providers via `StoredProcedureItemReader`
2. Iterate through the list and call another `StoredProcedureItemReader` for each provider (as input parameter) found in step 1.
3. The output of second SP is to be written to a CSV.

I have come up with below strategy:

1. Step 1 starts
2. SP ItemReader returns a list of providers.
3. In the ItemWriter, save the providers to `ExecutionContext`
4. Step 1 ends
5. Step 2 starts
6. Another SP ItemReader accesses the providers from `ExecutionContext`
7. Another ItemWriter writes the response to a CSV using FlatFileItemWriter

I am having trouble understanding how the second SP ItemReader will access the list of providers returned by the first SP ItemReader. Will a partition help here? Also, is there a better strategy to accomplish this?

EDIT 1:

Here is the original implementation of ItemProcessor (as enrichment):

```
@Scope("step")
public class FetchReportFromProviderProcessor implements
        ItemProcessor<RiscProvider, List<SogReportRecord>>, ItemStream {

    StoredProcedureItemReader<SogReportRecord> reader = new StoredProcedureItemReader<SogReportRecord>();
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Value("#{jobParameters['date']}")
    private String date;

    @Override
    public List<SogReportRecord> process(final RiscProvider item) throws Exception {

        SogReportRecord record = null;
        List<SogReportRecord> records = new ArrayList<SogReportRecord>();

        SqlParameter[] sqlParameters = new SqlParameter[] {new SqlParameter(OracleTypes.CURSOR)};           

        reader.setParameters(sqlParameters);
        reader.setPreparedStatementSetter(new PreparedStatementSetter() {

            @Override
            public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps) throws SQLException {
                ps.setString(0, item.getPrefix());
                ps.setString(1, date);
            }
        });

        while( (record = reader.read()) != null ) {
            records.add(record);
        }

        return records;
    }

    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        return dataSource;
    }

    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }

    @Override
    public void open(ExecutionContext executionContext)
            throws ItemStreamException {
        reader.setDataSource(dataSource);
        reader.setProcedureName("RISC_GET_DAYMOVEINOUT");
        reader.open(executionContext);      
    }

    @Override
    public void update(ExecutionContext executionContext)
            throws ItemStreamException {
        reader.update(executionContext);        
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws ItemStreamException {
        reader.close();     
    }

}
```

And the XML part:

```
<batch:job id="SOG_MOVEINOUT_REPORT_GENERATOR">
    <batch:step id="GET_REPORTS">
        <batch:tasklet>
            <batch:chunk reader="getProviders"
                processor="fetchRecordsFromProvider"
                writer="sogReportWriter" commit-interval="500" />
        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>

<!-- Reader to fetch list of providers -->
<bean id="getProviders" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.StoredProcedureItemReader">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="procedureName" value="RISC_GET_PROVIDER" />
    <property name="parameters">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlOutParameter">
                <constructor-arg index="0" value="providers" />
                <constructor-arg index="1">
                    <util:constant static-field="oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes.CURSOR" />
                </constructor-arg>
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="refCursorPosition" value="1" />
    <property name="rowMapper">
        <bean class="com.kpn.risc.ProviderRowMapper" />
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="fetchRecordsFromProvider" class="com.kpn.risc.FetchReportFromProviderProcessor">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="sogReportWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter" scope="step">
    <property name="resource" value="file:///${batch.job.report.dir}/report-#{stepExecutionContext['provider']}.csv" />
    <property name="lineAggregator">
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineAggregator">
            <property name="fieldExtractor">
                <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.PassThroughFieldExtractor" />
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

In the code above, the processor is delegating its work to an SP ItemReader. But the reader is unable to initialize properly before the `read()` method gets called. Is it possible or recommended to call an `ItemReader` inside `ItemProcessor`?

Comment: Hey did you find any good solution for such use case?

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing falls directly into the Driving Query pattern of batch processing.  In essence, a query defines ids (or in your case providers) that another query uses to drive it's queries.  Typically, the `ItemReader` reads the ids and passes each one to an `ItemProcessor` for enrichment (the "other" queries).  The result is then passed to an `ItemWriter`.

You can read more about the Driving Query pattern in the Common Batch Patterns section of the Spring Batch documentation here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/patterns.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply Michael. My first thought was to go for `ItemProcessor` as enrichment. I tried delegating processor to a `StoredProcedureItemReader`. (added code in question). But my reader needs the provider that is passed to the processor. How do I pass that to the reader before calling `start()` method?

Comment: I'll presume you mean the `open(ExecutionContext context)` method on your delegated `ItemReader`.  Since your reader isn't registered with Spring Batch as the reader, we don't automatically call the `ItemStream` lifecycle methods for you.  To register your delegated reader (which will cause those methods to be called), you need to manually register the reader as a stream.  The documentation on how to do that can be found in section 5.1.9 here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/configureStep.html

Comment: Ok, I have configured the delegated reader as a stream. But the delegated reader needs the provider as input parameter for stored procedure to initialize itself. I have the provider inside `process` method of processor. How do I pass it to the delegated reader?

Comment: Sorry.  I took you on a bit of a wrong track.  If you need to pass a parameter in, you'll need to writer your own DAO instead of using a reader since the reader executes the actual statement (opens the cursor) when `ItemStream#open` is called.  The only way using our reader would work is to create a new instance with each new provider.